# Oracle Connect By

Tags: sql, oracle

This question has some relation to my earlier question :
[Oracle SQL Connect By Logic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44844568/oracle-sql-connect-by-logic)

Table :

```
create table temp (emp_id varchar2(3), manager_id varchar2(3))
```

Data:

```
E10 E20
E20 E50
E30 E50
E40 E40
E50 E90
E90 E90
```

I would like to create a query to use connect by to go up the chain to find parent-parent records instead of fetching the child records.

The solution :

```
Select EMP_ID 
from temp
     Start with EMP_ID = 'E20'
     Connect by  NOCYCLE  EMP_ID =  Prior MANAGER_ID
order by EMP_ID
```

However as per my requirement I needed to fetch all the parents & the above query stops at E90. [Probably because of NOCYCLE as emp & manager are same at E90].

Query Output:

```
E20
E50
```

Required Output:

```
E20
E50
E90
```

Please advise.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems cycles are the problem.

Cycles are detected by looking at the columns with the PRIOR operator in the CONNECT BY clause.

To break such cycles, you need to add conditions that are trivially true but use the PRIOR operator on additional columns.

For example: to your CONNECT BY clause, add

```
and prior emp_id is not null
```

(assuming that emp_id can never be null).

Comment: I got what your trying to do.. However removing NOCYCLE causes  "ORA-01436: CONNECT BY loop in user data" error because the final parent in this situation  will be its own manager.

Comment: @pOrinG mathguy is not asking you to remove `connect by`, just add it to your connect query

Comment: Thank you, it works! @mathguy However I am not still not able to understand how it worked. Assuming that my loop reached E50-E90, it will then search for Emp_Id where [prior] Manager_Id = E90 i.e E90-E90. Then it will again search for Emp_Id where [prior] Manager_Id = E90 and still the prior emp_id should be E90. I guess I am missing something here.

Comment: @Sudipta Mondal Thank you.

Comment: @pOrinG - Oracle creates shorter rows for each row generated by CONNECT BY to keep track of cycles. The shorter rows, for tracking cycles, contain only the columns with the PRIOR keyword. By adding the trivial condition PRIOR emp_id is not null, you force Oracle to consider emp_id, in addition to manager_id, when it decides if there is a cycle. This allows it to add the row with (90, 90) after (50, 90). If it only looks at manager_id and not at emp_id, it would think that's a cycle already.

Comment: @mathguy Oh so because it stores both the prior emp_id & manager_id it thinks that the (90,90) is a legitimate record and not a cycle and displays it. Great! Thanks !!